# Python concatenating Lists

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have an List of list as below.

```
LED = [[255, 255, 255], [135, 234, 111], [244, 75, 128]]
```

AS you may have guessed these are Red/Green/Blue values for a number of LED's and I want them in this structure as I can address each member in the code by index. So i can change the value of LED[1] simply by writing new vaules to that item in the list.

However when it comes to writing them out i want a single list not a list of lists. so i have

```
For x in range (0, NumLED):
        LEDs = LEDs + LED[x]
```

Which would give

```
LEDs = [255, 255, 255, 135, 234, 111, 244, 75, 128]
```

Is there a better way to do this than looping through,for 3 LEDs it fine but for lists of hundreds I want to update the LED strip > 24 times a second, (and there are other things going on in the code) so any efficiency in concatenating this and save a few cycles would be great.

EDIT.

I tested the timing of using the sugested methods

```
python -mtimeit -s'l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]*99' 'sum(l, [])'  
100 loops, best of 3: 5.79 msec per loop  
python -mtimeit -s'l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]*99' '[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]'  
1000 loops, best of 3: 308 usec per loop
```

So it seems [item for sublist in l for item in sublist] is qutie a bit quicker.

Thanks all for the suggestions.

Aaron

There is a good explication of different methods of doing this with explication and timings in this question

[Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Cricket personal I think the answer linked below is a better one than this. it is more completed and readable for beginners.

Comment: That's probably the one I meant to grab instead, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a truly beautiful solution here

[Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

```
>>> LED = [[255, 255, 255], [135, 234, 111], [244, 75, 128]]
>>> [item for sublist in LED for item in sublist]
[255, 255, 255, 135, 234, 111, 244, 75, 128]
```

Comment: Perfect thank you for this perfect :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `sum`:

```
>>> LED = [[255, 255, 255], [135, 234, 111], [244, 75, 128]]
>>> sum(LED, [])
[255, 255, 255, 135, 234, 111, 244, 75, 128]
```

Comment: interesting! the standard way would seem to be the other the list comprehension idea but this is cool.

Comment: I timed these both using the Link from Андрей Череваткин answer.Both work but the first method is quite a bit fater than using Sum pi@Laserv3:~/APA102 $ python -mtimeit -s'l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]*99' 'sum(l, [])'
100 loops, best of 3: 5.79 msec per loop
pi@Laserv3:~/APA102 $ python -mtimeit -s'l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]*99' '[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 308 usec per loop
pi@Laserv3:~/APA102 $

Comment: Please note This is a O(N^2) operation. On each iteration a completely new list is built, keep this in mind when considering performance for huge lists this will be slow